# pyephem : mismatch position of planets with other sources

Tags: python, pyephem

i am trying to calculate the exact degree of planets on the zodiac  by pyephem but i faced with some problems. i need to extract the amounts with high accuracy . i made it better by changing Epoch value to now , but there are diffrents in second(degree an minutes are same as another valid source), is there any other factors to consider to make it more accurate?
as we know  results are different in each source, what is the exact position of planets and how we can calculate that?

i made this code better with applying epoch= ephem.now()

```
pl= ephem.Pluto()
pl.compute('2022/4/18 16:42:00')
print("coordinates:", ephem.Ecliptic(pl).lon)
print(ephem.constellation(pl))
sun.compute('2022/4/18 16:48:00', epoch= ephem.now())
print("coordinates:", ephem.Ecliptic(pl).lon , math.degrees(ephem.Ecliptic(pl).lon)  )
print(ephem.constellation(pl))
```

`coordinates: 298:15:33.9`       `('Sgr', 'Sagittarius')`

`coordinates: 298:34:15.4`    `298.57095635169946` `('Sgr', 'Sagittarius')`

but in my source it is `298(deg)34(min)08(sec)` in `capricorn`

Comment: What is "your source"?

Comment: Also, are you sure about the time zones used in you code and your source?

Comment: yes both time zones are same. i used this Android app 
[link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=astro_charts_pro.astro_charts_pro&hl=en&gl=US)
this app In addition to degree and minute shows the second and but this site 
[link](https://horoscopes.astro-seek.com/birth-chart-horoscope-online)
did not shows second. in compare of the Android app my codes results are few second(deg,min,second) different (Pluto in code 298:34:18.0 _ Pluto in app 298:34:11.0) that (18.0-11.0) 7 second cause more than 10 hours different in time for slow moving objects like Pluto

Comment: I also think there's a bug, for example it shows constellation position of moon in 1991/1/1 as Gemini. There's no way that is possible.

Comment: Figured it out, the astronomy calculations have diverged from astrological datasets. https://theconversation.com/why-your-zodiac-sign-is-probably-wrong-128818